# ADODb connection refresh after Insert/Update/Delete statement (Excel/Access linkage)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have made an Excel interface to interact with an Access database. The goal is that multiple people can open the Excel interface in read only mode but still act on the db all in the same time using ActiveX controls.

I have 3 buttons showing 3 userforms : one for "Insert entry", one for "Delete entry" and one for "Modify entry". In those userforms, we can respectively enter the values for a new entry that are then checked for validity by the VBA code, confirm the deletion of a row or modify the values of the entry selected by the user on the table's display. After data input + confirmation, an ADO connection is opened with the Access db and an sql query is executed.

As an example, here's the code for the "Delete" userform, the others are built on the same model.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lineArr() As Variant
    
    lineArr = returnSelectedLine
    
    Call doSqlInsert(CStr(lineArr(1)))
    Unload Me
        
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim lineArr() As Variant
    
    lineArr = returnSelectedLine
    
    Me.Label8.Caption = "Are you sure you want to delete the article number " & lineArr(1) & " ? This action is irreversible."

End Sub


Sub doSqlInsert(art As String)

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCon As String
    Dim quer As String

    
    
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\etwDb.accdb"
        
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strFile
        
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open strCon
    
    quer = "DELETE FROM Dvpt WHERE [Article] = " & art & ";"
    
    cn.Execute quer

    cn.Close
    
    Set cn = Nothing
    
End Sub

Function returnSelectedLine()

    Dim rw As Integer
    Dim res(0 To 7) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    
    
    rw = ActiveCell.Row
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste dvpt")
        For i = 0 To 7
            res(i) = .Cells(rw, i + 2)
        Next i
    End With
    
    returnSelectedLine = res
End Function
```

This works well and affects the data on the database correctly. However, this database is also displayed on the Excel file using a QueryTable object (the connection is in Read mode), which I try to refresh on termination of each userform (see `Private Sub UserForm_Terminate`), but this doesn't work consistantly. Sometimes, I need to make one or two more actions (or refresh once or twice more) to have the change being displayed, and sometimes it appears instantly.

**Indication :** the sheet is programmed so that only one unique cell can be selected, and only in the QueryTable area. The selection goes back to the table if the user tries to select something outside of it, so I can use `Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh` without ambiguity.

Has the ADO connection a time of execution ? Do I refresh my QueryTable the wrong way ? What causes this delay ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could try closing the connection before destroying it.  So open-update-close-destroy for cn.  Not sure i'll do some tests.

Comment: I just saw that one, I do it correctly in the other userforms, I think that is just a copy error. Thanks for noticing @Nathan_Sav !

Comment: Why use Excel as GUI instead of Access frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests being runned, it seems like the latency comes from the OLE connection, or from my company's network performances. In the first case, it probably can be  solved by changing the back end and/or front end technology (switching from Access/Excel to an Oracle db with an hardcoded C# front end), and in the second case nothing can be done.

Thanks to Nathan_Sav for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but an idea, too large for comment.  You could use the events of the connection, so create a class clsCustomConnection.  Like so

```
 Private WithEvents cn As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub Initialise(strConnectionString As String)
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
    cn.Open
End Sub

Public Sub Execute(strSQL As String)
    cn.Execute strSQL
End Sub

Private Sub cn_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, _
    adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    '   Refresh any query tables of interest, based on the Error/Status
End Sub
```

Then in a module have something like so:

```
Sub Testing()

Dim cnCustom As clsCustomConnection
Dim strConnectionString As String
Dim strSQL As String

Set cnCustom = New clsCustomConnection

cnCustom.Initialise strConnectionString
cnCustom.Execute strSQL

End Sub
```

This will use the connection to tell the rest of the code of it's success/fails, by using the events of the connection.

Comment: Okay so I tried it out. At first I want to thank you, because I didn't know we could instanciate objects in a way to handle their events at an application level, and you reminded me that VBA was an OO language (which is quite ironic as I come from Java as a junior OO application dev). The conclusion is that it does the same, so I am quite sure there is a delay between the ADO query and the availability for the Excel front end to the actuated data. But I am going to use my customSQL object to try and measure it, and report on it in here later on. Big thanks !

Comment: @MirageHF  i'll have a play and see if i can see.  Is it just delete that's causing the problems?  Is the DB stand alone or linked?  Can there be more than one user in at a time?  Try a row count from the DB before and after the update, check that the sql is working as you'd expect.  So Count, Delete, Count again.